# How to optimize recursive dp solution to Buy and Sell stocks 3 problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem - https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-iii

I have the following code-

```java
class Solution {
     Map<State, int[][]> dp;

    enum State {
        NONE,
        BUY
    }

    public int maxProfit(int[] prices) {
        dp = new HashMap<>();
        dp.put(State.NONE, new int[prices.length + 1][3]);
        dp.put(State.BUY, new int[prices.length + 1][3]);
        return maxP(prices, -1, 0, State.NONE, 2);
    }

    public int maxP(int prices[], int buyIndex, int index, State s, int k) {
        if (k == 0 && s == State.NONE)
            return 0;
        if (k < 0 || index >= prices.length)
            return 0;
        if (dp.get(s)[index][k] != 0 && k != 0)
            return dp.get(s)[index][k];

        int res = 0;
        switch (s) {
            case NONE -> {
                res = Math.max(maxP(prices, index, index + 1, State.BUY, k - 1),
                        maxP(prices, index + 1, index + 1, s, k));
            }
            case BUY -> {
                int profit = prices[index] - prices[buyIndex];
                res = Math.max(maxP(prices, buyIndex, index + 1, State.BUY, k),
                        (profit < 0) ? 0 : profit + maxP(prices, -1, index + 1, State.NONE, k));
            }
        }

        dp.get(s)[index][k] = res;
        return res;
    }
}
```

I have added memoization and it runs a top down search. If you are in None state i.e. you don't hold any stock, you can either stay in that state or move to a buy state.

If you are in buy state, you can stay in buy state or move to none state.

I am not looking for a bottom up solution and the ones I have seen provide 0 reasoning or logic to back it up. They are mostly copy pastes and I am not looking for internet points. I want to know why this code times out. I am performing every memoization I have seen in bottom up approaches.

Comment: I don't know Java but I wonder if you've done any "pre-processing" of the data. Suppose a sub-sequence of the data were `10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 7 ,9`. One might consider buying at `2`, but not at any of the other periods. Similarly, one might sell at `10` or `9` but not elsewhere. Consider, for example, `8`. One would not buy here because waiting until `2` would less costly, and it's clear one would not sell at `6` or `4`. Now consider `7`. One would not sell there because waiting until `9` would be preferable. Neither would one buy there as `2` would have been better...

Comment: ...You therefore should be able to eliminate buy/sell opportunities until you have a sequence of alternating increasing and decreasing values, with the troughs being buy opportunities and the peaks being sell opportunities.